# Comment Formatting topic for Help Center

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, comments, help-center

The new Help Center could really use a comment formatting article of some sort.

While I do know about https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting at the moment, I will eventually forget about it. Once that happens and I have a question about comment formatting, I will try going to the help center, and searching for "comment formatting" or perhaps "comments", hoping to find a link to such a reference.

At the moment I would be utterly disappointed. There does exist a help link for comments, but the fact that I have never noticed it before, means I won't see it once I forget about it again.

I'd suggest: an article that mentioned the basic italics, bold, code, and links syntax, and the mere existance of @username and short hands links, and which contains a link to editing help page for full details.

Comment: I do agree that sometimes I forget (or don't notice) that there's a  "help" on the right side of the comment box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've added a section on comment formatting to the [Markdown/HTML article](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) within the help center. (Unfortunately, we can't enable anchor links there, so you'll still have to scroll to find the section, but it's there and shows up when searching help.) I'm working on a separate article devoted to when to use comments and how they work, which will cover the comment replying. Both can/will link to the [editing help](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) page for further details.